# How to change the default resampling method in ArcGIS 10.2.2 to Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, resampling, mosaic-dataset

When creating a reference mosaic dataset in ArcGIS 10.2.2., the default resampling is Nearest Neighbor but I'm using continuous data so I need to change the resampling method.

When using the Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset tool, I don't see an option for changing the default resampling method.

I've tried a couple things, in Environment Settings > Raster Storage, it seems you can only change the pyramid resampling method. In Advanced ArcMap Settings, changing the default resampling technique to something other than Nearest Neighbor doesn't seem to work either. After changing these both to Bilinear, and re-running the Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset tool, checking in the results window I still see Resampling Method: NEAREST.

For some more background information, these are the steps I have taken: 1) Create a file geodatabase 2) Create a raster catalog 3) Load rasters into the catalog with the load from workspace option 4) Create a referenced mosaic dataset.